# Select multiple

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem on saving my data

```
<label>Obat</label>
    <?php echo "<select class='form-control' multiple='multiple' name='kd_obat[]' id='selectBox' onclick='changeFunc();'>";
    if (count($get2)) {
    foreach ($get2 as $list) {
    echo "<option value='". $list['kd_obat'] . "'>" . $list['nm_obat'] . "</option>";
    }
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

When i select multiple and save, it works and it be like KO001, KO002 (based kd_obat) , i use implode for make that be string

But how can i showing the selected option on input form?

```
<label>Resep</label>
<input type="text" name="resep" class="form-control" id="resep"/>
```

In resep i want to show the selected option based their nm_obat
For example Hidrokortosin 1mg, Hidrokortosin 5mg

Thanks

Comment: I would consider that the foreach loop also create a new array, with only `$list['nm_obat']` values, so you could simply use the  `value` attribute from `input` and print it as `implode(',', $new_array_with_nm_obat_values);`

Comment: am i can use something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/dk40t1h5/
but in my code http://pastebin.com/vJKJcisN
it isnt work
can u help me?

Comment: Your code is not working because `$('#resep').text()` should be actually `$('#resep').val(str)`. See that in the fiddle example, the DOM element is a `<textarea>` and your example is a `<input>`. `<textarea>` elements have jQuery's `.text()` method, but `<input>` don't as these do not have content inside their tag, but as a value of it.

Comment: oh im forgot to change to textarea
but its still not work even i change to textarea

Comment: In the example you're using a pure javascript happening just after the code. Are you wrapping your javascript code with `$(document).ready(function(){`?

Comment: like this '$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#obat" )'
.....
}

Comment: I'll move my answer as an aswer since comments do not support multiline code.

Answer (score 0):

So you had problems with your original code since using `<input>` element and trying to append value to it using jQuery's `text()` method. As I said, `<input>` elements do not have `text()` method as they don't have any content, but they have `value` attribute, so using jQuery's `val()` method would correct your code.

Having trouble with Javascript yet to work, I suggest you to wrap your code with document ready function.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#obat" ).change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $( "#obat option:selected" ).each(function() {
            str += $( this ).text() + " ";
        });
        $( "#resep" ).val( str );
    }).change();
});
```